# Exporting a list from a function

Tags: c, list, for-loop, struct

I have a problem in C language.

This for cycle creates a list with the info of a file. "pl", "pc" and "pv" per row.

And prints the information per row too, 3 numbers.

=====================================================

## Ex. 1

```
for(i = 0, aux = base->prox; i < p; aux = aux->prox, i++){

    aux = (celula *)malloc(sizeof(celula));
    fscanf(file, "%d %d %d", &(aux->pl) , &(aux->pc), &(aux->pv));
    printf("%d %d %d\n", aux->pl , aux->pc, aux->pv);

}
```

=====================================================

In the second example, I print the information out of the for cycle, but in another for cycle that goes through the list created in the previous for cycle.

=====================================================

## Ex. 2

```
for(i = 0, aux = base->prox; i < p; aux = aux->prox, i++){

    aux = (celula *)malloc(sizeof(celula));
    fscanf(file, "%d %d %d", &(aux->pl) , &(aux->pc), &(aux->pv));
    /*printf("%d %d %d\n", aux->pl , aux->pc, aux->pv);*/

}

for(aux = base; aux != NULL; aux = aux->prox){

    printf("%d %d %d\n", aux->pl , aux->pc, aux->pv);

}
```

=====================================================

Now, the problem is: In the first example, it prints the information normally. In the second example, instead of printing the information normally just like in the first example, it prints only one line with "0 0 0".

What's the diferent between the 1st and the 2nd example? Shouldn't it do the same?

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Even though the first example seems to do what you want, there is a bug in both of them.  You should not be mallocing memory for aux every time through the for loop.  This will cause a memory leak and cause you to loose the values you read in with fscanf.

You should malloc the memory for aux outside of the for loop.  Then use the for loop to read values into memory using fscanf.

Comment: Tried this...

 aux = (celula *)malloc(sizeof(celula));

 for(i = 0, aux = base->prox; i < p; aux = aux->prox, i++){
  
  fscanf(file, "%d %d %d", &(aux->pl) , &(aux->pc), &(aux->pv));
  /*printf("%d %d %d\n", aux->pl , aux->pc, aux->pv);*/
  
    }

Segmentation Fault.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0, aux = base->prox; i < p; aux = aux->prox, i++){

    aux = (celula *)malloc(sizeof(celula));
    fscanf(file, "%d %d %d", &(aux->pl) , &(aux->pc), &(aux->pv));
    /*printf("%d %d %d\n", aux->pl , aux->pc, aux->pv);*/

}
```

In your for loop you are doing `aux = (celula *)malloc(sizeof(celula));` which overwrites the `aux` taken from `aux = aux->prox`. So fscanned data goes in new allocated memory and not in linked list.

So when you again refer the list in another loop, it does not have the read data.

You don't need to allocate `aux` in for loop, if the linked list is already created. So remove `malloc()` from the loop.

```
for(i = 0, aux = base->prox; i < p; aux = aux->prox, i++){
    //not needed
    //aux = (celula *)malloc(sizeof(celula));
    fscanf(file, "%d %d %d", &(aux->pl) , &(aux->pc), &(aux->pv));
    /*printf("%d %d %d\n", aux->pl , aux->pc, aux->pv);*/

}
```

If the list node is not allocated, allocate it and add it into the list appropriately.

Comment: Tried this...

 aux = (celula *)malloc(sizeof(celula));

 for(i = 0, aux = base->prox; i < p; aux = aux->prox, i++){
  
  fscanf(file, "%d %d %d", &(aux->pl) , &(aux->pc), &(aux->pv));
  /*printf("%d %d %d\n", aux->pl , aux->pc, aux->pv);*/
  
    }

Segmentation Fault.

Comment: @JoãoFilipe, that seems some problem in how you have built the linked list.